# Visual Studio Report Project

Tags: visual-studio-2012, reporting-services

In my report dataset I have a column call "Period" that contains s string like "From August 2012 until December 2013".
In my VS Report project, I need a a tablix that has a column based on the first date in short form (e.g. Aug 12) from the above.
I understand that in SQL Server, I can achieve this by using the following statement

```
select  substring(Period,6,3) + ' ' + substring(Period,(CHARINDEX(' until',Period)-2),2)
```

But in the VS Report expression, the above statement is not recognized and therefore cannot be used.

I have tried searching for an equivalent in Report expression format but have not come across a similar case.

Would really appreciate if you can advise me how to do this in Report expression language.

Answer (score 1):

Report expressions use VBA syntax not Sql, so `Substring` is `Mid` and `CharIndex` is `IndexOf`:

```
=Mid(Fields!Period.Value, 6, 3) & " " & Mid(Fields!Period.Value, (IndexOf(" until", Fields!Period.Value)-2, 2)
```

Comment: Thank you so much for the answer. I didn't realize report expressions use VBA, all this while I was thinking since it's part of SQL Server, then it by reduction it must be in SQL too!